# is there a way to give column names to pd.read_clipboard() as it is treating first row of data as column names

Tags: pandas, clipboard

I am using pd.read_clipboard() function to get an excel table that doesnt have column names as first row . The dataframe returned has first row as column labels. How to fix that.

[image: This is a simple table with no header row]

I would like results to be
[image: desired]

and not this 
[image: incorrect]

Answer (score 1):

Though not showing up on help for read_clipboard() function , passing read_clipboard(names=['c1','c2']) where c1 and c2 are the column names fixes the  read_clipboard() function to not treat first row as column names i.e provide column names to avoid having the function treat first row as column names

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(names=['c1', 'c2'])
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of the previous answer, though.